# The people on top don't have it

Tags: riddle

The people on top don't have it.

The people at the bottom do.

If you don't have it you die.

what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too broad for a riddle it even might be

> Oxygen

The people on top don't have it.

> We're talking real heights where Oxygen is scarce

The people at the bottom do.

> Everyone else has an oxygen supply

If you don't have it you die.

> You can't breath and you suffocate

Comment: Got beaten by 2 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

> Heart.

Reason:

> Figuratively, people at the top don't seem to have it; people at the
>  bottom do. Literally, if you don't have one you will die.

Comment: Oh, this is a very nice answer imho

Answer (score 1):

> Air and air pressure

Reason:

People at the Top... :

> If you are in space or very high in the air (an airplane perhaps), one you won't have any oxygen in space. Two, if the air pressure is not normal, you will die or receive critical injuries. That is why the air pressure is regulated in all airplanes. I wouldn't say the same for those climbing Mount Everest. They still survived or died due to being too cold or trapped in an avalanche.

People at The Bottom... :

> They have plenty of air. We need air to breathe and survive and to have plants and animals to consume.

Final Answer:

> Air and air pressure!